# how to use codemirror in Vue.js to send line number?

Tags: vue.js, frontend, codemirror

I want to use codemirror in Vue.js to implement two text areas. When I select some lines code in area1, the same lines code in area2 should be highlighted.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

I come up with two examples.

First, synchronize selection:

Add event listener for `cursorActivity` event whenever this event trigger get selection details by `getCursor` method then set it to second editor by `setSelection` method.

```
firstEditor.on("cursorActivity", () => {
  let head = this.ca.getCursor("head");
  let anchor = this.ca.getCursor("anchor");
  secondEditor.setSelection(anchor, head);
});
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7nx0wm9k5)

Second, highlight selection lines:

Again, add event listener for `cursorActivity` event whenever this event trigger get start and end lines of selection by `getCursor` method then highlight these lines in second editor.

To highlight lines, The CodeMirror has a plugin call `active-line` which enable by `styleActiveLine` option. But unfortunately I cannot get this works for multiple lines so I modify it for this case.

```
const WRAP_CLASS = "CodeMirror-activeline";
const BACK_CLASS = "CodeMirror-activeline-background";
const GUTT_CLASS = "CodeMirror-activeline-gutter";

const clearActiveLines = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.lineCount(); i++) {
    this.removeLineClass(i, "wrap", WRAP_CLASS);
    this.removeLineClass(i, "background", BACK_CLASS);
    this.removeLineClass(i, "gutter", GUTT_CLASS);
  }
};

const setActiveLines = function(from, to) {
  clearActiveLines.call(this);
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    this.addLineClass(i, "wrap", WRAP_CLASS);
    this.addLineClass(i, "background", BACK_CLASS);
    this.addLineClass(i, "gutter", GUTT_CLASS);
  }
};

CodeMirror.defineExtension("setActiveLines", setActiveLines);

CodeMirror.defineExtension("clearActiveLines", clearActiveLines);
```

Then use it.

```
firstEditor.on("cursorActivity", () => {
  if (firstEditor.getSelection()) {
    let from = this.ca.getCursor("from");
    let to = this.ca.getCursor("to");
    secondEditor.setActiveLines(from.line, to.line);
  } else {
    secondEditor.clearActiveLines();
  }
});
```

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/82jq9k29z2)

I'm not much familiar with CodeMirror but I hope this help.